# How to upload mp3 to mongodb using express, mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, mongoose

I am building music app, but I do not know how can I upload music to database, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

To store files in mongodb, you can convert the mp3 into binary or base64, then store the binary data.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your support! Could you recommend any article, video, or a course?

Comment: You've given relatively little details, so I cannot help you much. In essence: (1) Import mp3 file into JS, (2) convert data into binary format, (3) store binary data into mongodb. Each of these steps can be solved separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant store a file into a database, you only can save it in a storage. And in your database, you can put the path of your file location.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload music to any database. Upload your mp3 file to aws or cloudinary or to your local storage system, get the link and save that to the database.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your support! Did you mean mp3 not image?

Comment: Yes I mean mp3.